# Visual Studio - Step into (F11) code in another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So here's my situation.

I have a Project A wherein I attached it to an IIS Worker Process to be able to debug it. I have placed a breakpoint on a line of code which calls a method on a referenced project (Project B). During debugging, when I pressed F11, since the method is from a referenced project, it doesn't step into that code.

But I wanted to know how that method in Project B works so I need to somehow step into it. May I know if it is possible to step into a code from a referenced project from Project A given that I debugged Project A from another process?

I tried Project A -> Attached to IIS Worker Process and then Project B (opened in another Visual Studio instance) -> attached to devenv.exe of Project A but it doesn't work.

Inputs much appreciated.

Comment: The usual way to deal with this is to open Project B, set a breakpoint where you want to start debugging, and set Project A as the host application. You then start Project A using Windows Explorer by double-clicking it and run Project A as usual to the point where it calls into Project B. It's the same way you would debug a DLL - by setting breakpoints in the DLL code and then running the app that will call the DLL's code.

Comment: Do you have to do this on some live IIS? Can you not do it on a local iis/dev web server running the whole solution in debug?

Comment: @KenWhite how can I set Project A as host application?

Comment: @CaiusJard website is hosted in local IIS